# Замена значения value

Tags: javascript

Есть форма, при выборе одного значения из списка появляется текст с описанием, в value стоят значения с 1 до 3 и соответственно ко мне на почту приходит заявка в поле Оплата стоит (1,2,3) а мне нужно сделать так чтобы в полях value стоял текст. Подскажите как сделать чтобы при оформление заявки у меня на почте в значениях value был текст вместо цифр.

```
<script>
help=new Array();
help[0]="";
help[1]="<p>Текст 1 (Онлайн оплата)";
help[2]="<p>Текст 2 (Доверительный платёж)";
help[3]="<p>Текст 3 (Скидка за отзыв в группе)";
</script>

<select name="Oplata" id="Oplata" x-autocompletetype="Oplata" class="select" required onChange="document.getElementById('text').innerHTML=help[this.value];">
<option value="0">Способ оплаты:</option>
<option value="1">450 руб. (Онлайн оплата)</option>
<option value="2">450 руб. (Доверительный платёж)</option>
<option value="3">400 руб. (Скидка за отзыв в группе)</option>
</select>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="input" id="text"></div>
```

Comment: Несколько вопросов. Куда приходит и где обрабатывается этот `select`? Каким образом формируется почтовое сообщение? Почему поставили метку java?

Comment: Я думаю вопрос относится не к Java, а JavaScript :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<select ... onChange="document.getElementById('OplataText').value=document.getElementById('text').innerHTML=help[this.value];">
...

<input type="hidden" id="OplataText" name="OplataText" />
```

или

```js
var help = {};
help[0]="";
help["Онлайн"]="<p>Текст 1 (Онлайн оплата)";
help["Доверительный"]="<p>Текст 2 (Доверительный платёж)";
help["Скидка"]="<p>Текст 3 (Скидка за отзыв в группе)";
```

```html
<select name="Oplata" id="Oplata" x-autocompletetype="Oplata" class="select" required 
  onChange="document.getElementById('text').innerHTML=help[this.value];">
  <option value="0">Способ оплаты:</option>
  <option value="Онлайн">450 руб. (Онлайн оплата)</option>
  <option value="Доверительный">450 руб. (Доверительный платёж)</option>
  <option value="Скидка">400 руб. (Скидка за отзыв в группе)</option>
</select>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="input" id="text"></div>
```

Comment: мне нужно вместо value="1" value="2" value="3" написать value="Онлайн" value="Доверительный" value="Скидка" но если я так сделаю скрипт не будет срабатывать

Comment: @Блондинка ну, вам на сервере, где вы обрабатываете надо создать такой же массив с аналогичным расположением нужных элементов. Когда вам придет с ответа идентификатор, вы просто этот идентификатор с того массива возвращаете. Какая проблема?

Comment: Мне сделали сайт а программист пропал, я сама в этом не понимаю. я думала как в обычном html меняем и все, а тут если написать как я хочу то скрипт не срабатывает